# S3 amazon server fix access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Issue:
I need to make fix access into our server using S3 by using password to get in.  I want to make it so everyone can access a particular folder through a password we give them. Right now we are giving them the secret key which then they have access to everything.

At present I login from s3brower with Access key and Secret access key provided. But this gives too much info. We would like everyone to have there own password and we set the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

First, S3 does not behave like an FTP server. You can create an IAM user for each of your users and each user can have a password as well as an access key and a secret key. However, the password will only allow the user to log in to the console. Using a program like S3Browser will still require the user's access key and secret key.

You can give each user an IAM policy to set what objects they can access in S3, see [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke).

Answer (score 0):

AWS don't support this yet. I made a third party [s3 explorer](https://www.filestash.app/aws-s3-explorer.html) from which you can create shared link that are protected by a password:

[image]